# Computed properties in Ember.js object function definition

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm updating to the 1.0.0 release of Ember js, and am dealing with the error "Ember.Object.create no longer supports computing properties".  For most of these errors, which look like:

```
Class.controller = Class.Other.create({
    something: function () {}.property()
});
```

Can be fixed with:

```
Class.controller = Class.Other.extend({
    something: function () {}.property()
});
Class.controller = Class.controller.create();
```

The situation I'm having trouble dealing with is:

```
Class.controller = Class.Other.create({
    something: Class.Button.create({
        action: function () {}.property()
    });
});
```

How do I fix this so that it's valid with the newest version of Ember?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `extend` and `create`:

```
Class.controller = Class.Other.extend({
    something: Class.Button.extend({
        action: function () {}.property()
    }).create()
}).create();
```